# Performing calculations on a tab-delimited file

Tags: python, arrays, csv

I'm still learning Python and I still don't know how to work with arrays.

I'm want to read a tab-delimited file as for example (but in my case I will have about 400 rows):

```
  Col1      Col2
  0.0001    0.6
  0.0001    0.5
  0.000006  0.8
  0.0001    0.0003
  0.002     1
  0.002     3
```

I want to get the following output:

```
Col1      Col2
0.0001    0.36676667
0.000006  0.8
0.002     2
```

So I wanna keep the same value in **Col1** but taking the mean of values in **Col2** which corresponds to the same value in **Col1**.

I can read an array using :

```
  arr = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', dtype=None, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1)
```

but I don't know how to make these operations and making a new file with the new generated data.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) with `list` as the default argument.

Take the value from the first column as the key, and append the second value.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

# Gather the data from the CSV file
d = defaultdict(list)
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        d[float(row[0])].append(float(row[1]))

# Print the mean.
for k in d.keys():
    print k, sum(d[k])/len(d[k])
```

Comment: Thanks! but I'm getting the following error message : **ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0.0001 0.6** Any idea why?

Comment: @Fabs: you probably have to set the delimiter in `csv.reader`.

Comment: It did work know! Thanks! How cool was this answer! I hope one day I'll know all these python functions! :)

Comment: @Fabs: Keep a link to the [standard library documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/) in your browser favorites. :-)